# Módulo com vários controllers no Zend 2

Tags: php, zend

Estou com dificuldade para criar um módulo com vários *controllers* no Zend 2. Seria, seria por exemplo:

```
admin/user/
admin/user/add
admin/user/edit
admin/user/delete
```

Como ajusto as rotas para obter essas URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ficheiro `module.config.php` do teu módulo, tens que declarar os `invokables` para os `controllers` bem como adicionar as `routes` para cada `controller`.

## [Routing and controllers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html)

## 1ª Solução

Para o que descreves, o exemplo presente na documentação para um módulo de nome `Album` com várias ações num `controller` com o nome `AlbumController` lida bem com o teu problema:

[image: Páginas do módulo "Album"]

Conteúdo do ficheiro `module.config.php`:

```
return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
         ),
     ),

     // The following section is new and should be added to your file
     'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
             'album' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                         'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),

     'view_manager' => array(
         'template_path_stack' => array(
             'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
         ),
     ),
 );
```

## 2ª Solução

Múltiplos `controllers` também é possível, se necessário e pode ser atingido declarando os diversos `controllers` e as diversas `routes` da seguinte forma:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController', // 1º controller
        'Album\Controller\User' => 'Album\Controller\UserController',   // 2º controller
    ),
),
```

E as rotas:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/user[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\User',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Onde assim vais ter algo do género:

```
view/
  album/
    album/             
      index.phtml
    user/             
      index.phtml
```